# Difference between volatile and __volatile__

Tags: c, gcc, volatile

What is the difference between `volatile` and `__volatile__` in C code compiled with gcc?

I was looking in the Linux source code and I noticed that some places use `__asm__ __volatile__` others use `asm volatile` and others use `__asm__ volatile`.

I have not seen `__volatile__` used without `__asm__`, while I have seen `volatile` used in a variety of other places.

Is there any difference between what `__volatile__` and `volatile` do?  If so what is it? Or if not is there a reason that `__volatile__` is used sometimes?

Comment: Non-standard keywords must use leading underscores.  But that's a rule that got added to the language too late to allow compilers to drop the non-standard usage without breaking a lot of existing code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just for backward compatibility with legacy code. Keywords that were added to C in later life, such as `inline`, `volatile`, `asm`, etc, have underscore prefix/suffix versions (`__inline__`, `__asm__`, `__volatile__`, etc) so that you can use them in legacy code that already uses the unadorned names as types/functions/variables/whatever. There is a command line switch which controls this, `-ansi` - when you compile with `gcc -ansi ...` only the underscore versions of these newer keywords are recognised.

Comment: That really doesn't explain `__volatile__`, though; I'm guessing it might be something to do with the rule against using the `volatile` type qualifier in the Linux kernel...

Answer (score 4):

#### Because of `-ansi`

Although a real `-ansi` program would not use `asm(),` there needs to be a way to include an asm macro in a header even when the program itself is built with `-ansi`. (With `-ansi`, gcc doesn't include extensions which conflict with strict ISO C, like new keywords.)

A properly namespaced alternative `__asm__` was necessary for `asm`, which could not be defined by the system in `-ansi` mode. Now, this wasn't strictly necessary with `volatile,` which has been a keyword for a long time, but perhaps by inertia someone also (and unnecessarily) made a `__volatile__` (reserved system name format) to go with `volatile`, even if the program would have been legal `-ansi` either way.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Paul R's response;

Given that you haven't defined any of the below names:

- `asm` and `volatile` are **language** keywords. How do you know? They have no underscore before or after them, hence they are keywords in the **language**.
- `_something_` (one underscore) is a reserved **compiler** keyword, type, macro, etc.
- `__asm__`, `__volatile__` and `__whatever_else__` (two underscores) are **standard library** keywords, macros, etc.

Knowing this will help you find out what things mean in the future, what to google and where to find the references to them.

Comment: this is incorrect; the trend is to define new language keywords with leading underscore and title case (`_Bool`, `_Alignof`) and provide lower case variants as macros (`bool`, `alignof`); standard macros are upper case and surrounded by two underscores (`__FILE__`, `__STDC_VERSION__`); there are also special cases (`__func__` - which is not a macro, but a predefined identifier, `__alignof_is_defined` which is a macro); compiler and libc are free to do whatever they want but of course should follow the rules for reserved identifiers as specified by the ISO standard

Comment: @Christoph, you're right, these aren't facts, just usually very common and therefore a help when trying to find out what something is. But again, you're right. It's nasty if you want the whole truth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 0):

`__asm__` is an alternative of asm. They mean the same thing. I can find the relevant information in GCC documentation.

For volatile and __volatile, [1](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) and [2](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) say that it means "If your assembly statement must execute where you put it". But I browse GCC documents [3](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and fails to find such a explanation. I don't know which answer is correct either: the answer given in [2](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html) or answer given by Paul R.